# How to put a custom login menu in a page?

Tags: 6, routes

I'm totally new to Drupal and I'm using v.6.xx.

I've managed to remove the "login" menu via Admin panel.

Now I'd like to create a custom "page" (= no menu) with a customized login form, and once authentified, show a menu with some options and the "disconnect" option.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok your question has several parts:

(The standard login form can be accessed through a block, or going to the /user path while logged out)

Custom login form:

- http://picxelplay.com/blog/theming-drupal-6-registration-login-and-request-new-password-pages-not-just-forms
- http://blog.aphexcreations.net/2009/04/theming-drupal-user-login-form.html
- http://drupal.org/node/154236 (outdated)

Custom 'menu':

- Create a block that has a link to /logout, going to that path will automatically log out your users. Make sure that the block visibility is only for authenticated users.
- Add any other links or options you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did have found the lastest link, but as you've noticed, it's outdated and I didn't manage to create my custom login, I hope I'll have more chances with the 2 first links ;) Thank you!

Comment: If you have any questions/problems, just post them here, and I'll do my best to answer them.